# setState() not triggering re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there anything inherently wrong with this code?

Part in question is this:

```
// Update state and trigger re-render
// NOT WORKING
this.setState({ subsections });
```

State is not being set when I call setState(). Though the data is there in the `subsections` object. I've used the same code patterns on other methods and it works as intended.

The data is saved in Parse too by the way, if I refresh the page it's there.

```
import React from "react";
import Parse from 'parse';

import Subsections from './Subsections';
import AddSubsectionForm from './AddSubsectionForm';

class Manage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addSubsection = this.addSubsection.bind(this);

    // Set initial state
    this.state = {
      subsections: {}
    };
  }

  addSubsection(subsection) {
    // Make copy of state
    const subsections = {...this.state.subsections};

    // Create new object
    var SubsectionTest = Parse.Object.extend('SubsectionTest');
    var subsectionTest = new SubsectionTest();

    // Save object, then update state on return
    subsectionTest.save({
      name: subsection.name,
      description: subsection.description
    }).then(function(newSubsection) {
      console.log('Has saved id of: '+newSubsection.id);

      // Add new subsection to local state
      subsections[newSubsection.id] = subsection;

      // Log updatd subsections object
      console.log(subsections);

      // Update state and trigger re-render
      // NOT WORKING
      this.setState({ subsections });
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log('Error:');
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  /*
    Loads subsections from Parse and displays them.
    Code removed for clarity.
  */
  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadMenuItems();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.subsections) {
      return (
        <div className="subsections">
          <div className="mt3 border-top">
            <h3 className="mt1 bold s2">Subsections</h3>

            <div className="mt1">
              <Subsections subsections={this.state.subsections} />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="mt3 border-top">
            <AddSubsectionForm addSubsection={this.addSubsection}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default Manage;
```

Comment: You should probably `else { return null; }` in your render() function (not an answer, I know.. it just stuck out to me)

Comment: Not an answer to OP, but another reason for issue (setState not triggering render) is forgetting to return true in shouldComponentUpdate().

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `this` isn't bound in your promise's `then` handler:

```
}).then(function(newSubsection) {
```

Since you're using es2015 classes, you probably can use an arrow function (which binds `this` to its lexical scope):

```
}).then(newSubSection => {
```

The other option would be to explicitly bind it:

```
}).then(function(newSubsection) {
...
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: I implemented the arrow function but it still doesn't update State. I forgot to mention I had previously explicitly binded it like your second example there. Very odd to me especially since the same method produces the expected result in another function in the same component.

Comment: Does _anything_ happen? Error message in the console?

Comment: Well, yes, it seems now `render() { ... return ( ...` is running again after saving (based on console logging a message) but not with updated State. The console.log shows that `subsections` has the new object, but when I inspect the component it does not have the new object in State.

Comment: That seems odd. Maybe move the `const subsections = {...this.state.subsections};` to inside your promise handler?

Comment: That didn't work either, same behavior as before. I can update the answer with the full code? Maybe I'm doing something dumb somewhere else. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: You probably want to pass the constructor args up to `Component` as well: `constructor(...args) { super(...args);` (not sure if that affects _this_ issue, but I've seen it cause some weird things if left out)

Answer (score 1):

the context of `this` is lost, you can try binding the callback to `this`

```
   var callback = function (newSubsection) {
       console.log('Has saved id of: ' + newSubsection.id);
           .....
       this.setState({
           subsections
       });
   };
   callback = callback.bind(this);
   subsectionTest.save({
       name: subsection.name,
       description: subsection.description
   }).then(callback),
   function (error) {
       console.log('Error:');
       console.log(error);
   });
```

If you are using [Babel preset stage 2](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/) you can acheive this by using arrow functions

```
      description: subsection.description
      }).then(newSubsection = > {
              console.log('Has saved id of: ' + newSubsection.id);
```

Comment: `.then(newSubsection = () => {` gives a `newSubsection not defined` error which makes me think I'm not using Babel preset stage 2? (Sorry, not too advanced of a dev, more of a designer)

Comment: I think he meanth `.then(newSubsection => {`